# Would it be better to post code with or without the terminal prompt?

Tags: discussion, answers, code

This is with regards to answering questions in scripting language tags such as Python, where you can also execute code in an interpreter/REPL session. I am talking about these kind of prompts:

```
In [554]: ...
Out[554]: ...
```

And,

```
>>> ...
```

When pasting code and output from interpreter, I do not remove the prompts, simply because.

However, if users wish to copy such code, they'd have to manually remove the prompts themselves. This might actually make them want to choose an answer that *doesn't* have those prompts, simply because it is easier to work those solutions into their existing code, regardless of whether it is a better solution or not.

The alternative would be to write code in scripts and then run them from the terminal, but this is cumbersome and slow - especially when debugging and validating.

What would be the best thing to do?

Comment: I'm not especially interested in optimizing example code for copy-pasting, and I don't think you should be either.

Answer (score 7):

I personally like it when code blocks contain `$` in front of Linux commands for example. It makes it so that you have to copy each line individually in a set of commands instead of selecting the whole thing and letting it loose in your terminal.

In my opinion, the same goes for programming. People really shouldn't be blindly copy-pasting code from answers but try to use them to figure out an answer on their own using the knowledge they got after reading it.

Therefore I believe leaving console prompts in can be beneficial both from a cautiousness standpoint as well as providing context on where and how the presented output was produced.